# Clarity Modal inside stackview overlaps UI elements

Tags: css, angular, vmware-clarity, clarity

I have a clarity modal, which is there under stack-block-content.
When I open this modal it overlaps all other UI elements.

I tried setting z-index to very large number but still it did not work.

```
<dt class="stack-block-label">Label 2</dt>
    <dd class="stack-block-content">
      <button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="basic=true">Click This</button>

      <clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="basic">
          <h3 class="modal-title">I have a nice title</h3>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <p>But not much to say...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline" (click)="basic = false">Cancel</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="basic = false">Ok</button>
          </div>
      </clr-modal>
    </dd>
    <div class="stack-children">
        <div class="stack-block">
            <dt class="stack-block-label">Sub-label 1</dt>
            <dd class="stack-block-content">Sub-content 1</dd></dt>
```

Can anyone please help get me out of there.
Here is my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-datagrid-basic-eruq88

In  chrome developer tool, if I disable -webkit-mask-image property from stack-view it works well. But in my code, when I overwrite stack-view class it doesn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `<clr-modal></clr-modal>` div out so that it is under the `<div class="main-container"></div>` div. This will bring it out of the inner divs and overlay the modal on top of everything. Setting `z-index` on child elements will not work.

Comment: yes, i know i can do that but in my code, its actually a component and need to be there.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is throwing an `*ngIf` on the `stack-header` like so: `<h4 class="stack-header" *ngIf="!basic">`. This will remove it from the view and look a little weird but the modal will cover the whole screen.

Comment: @SpellChucker is right that you should move the modal outside of the stack view, then the modal should overlay properly.